# after disabling all boot priorities I cannot access the bios of my samsung np500p4c-s07ae

Tags: bios

After disabling all boot priorities I cannot access the bios of my samsung np500p4c-s07ae, even if I press all possible  function keys.

Comment: There's also something wrong with your Caps Lock key it seems.

Comment: how can default bios setting ? if I can`t access bios?whenever I open the laptop it show samsung logo and then down the system then  repeat logo then down.. I already reset or takeoff the cmos bat. to think it will reset the bios setting  but its effect anything... please help.

Comment: Did you check the computer's manual?

Comment: I lost the manual sir.. why even I takeoff the cmos bat. it doesn`t reset?.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which key you're supposed to hit, but you should be able to enter BIOS by holding it down while turning power on.

Make sure you've shut down the system previously, not just put it on standby or similar.

If you're on Windows 8+ and UEFI, the options for System Restore might offer you an option to boot into the UEFI settings as well.

Comment: how can default bios setting ? if I can`t access bios?whenever I open the laptop it show samsung logo and then down the system then repeat logo then down.. I already reset or takeoff the cmos bat. to think it will reset the bios setting but its doesn`t affect anything... please help. sir